# Нужно изменить приоритет процесса C#

Tags: c#, процесс

Имеется код:

```
Process thisProc = Process.GetCurrentProcess();    
thisProc.PriorityClass = ProcessPriorityClass.Idle;
```

Этот код изменяет приоритет процесса программы, которая компилирует код.
А мне нужно изменить приоритет процесса посторонней программы.
Я пробовал это сделать сам, у меня ничего не получилось

Answer (score 5):

Вы пишите `Process.GetCurrentProcess();` - не удивительно, что процесс получаете текущего приложения.

Для доступа к другому процессу, надо его найди:

- Cкажем по имени `Process.GetProcessesByName("MyProc");`, в ответ вы получите массив найденных процессов, если процесс один, то можете дописать `.FirstOrDefault();` и в ответ получите первый элемент, который найдет `GetProcessesByName("MyProc")`.
- Можете указать точный Id процесса.
  `Process.GetProcessById(id);` - Тут в ответе будет только один уникальный процесс, который соответствует заданному id (int).

Учтите, что для работы вам скорей всего потребуются права администратора!

Comment: Как найти id определенного приложения? Допустим firefox.exe
Оно при каждом запуске разное

Comment: @Varagian Ищите по имени процесса. Ну а так, весь список процессов получается с помощью `Process.GetProcesses()`. Используйте просто `var ff = Process.GetProcessesByName("firefox").FirstOrDefault();`  в ответ получите именно первый найденный процесс Firefox. Ему уже и меняйте приоритет. Если процессов несколько, как я уже писал в ответе - не добавляйте в конце `FirstOrDefault()`, получите список всех процессов с именем Firefox, дальше циклом по ним и меняйте им приоритет.